# Formula to read text as number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: picture of chart]
Okay so as you can see each column has a value of 1-3. Currently there's just a basic formula at the end that works out the percentage by adding whats there and then dividing by the total possible if every column was 3 and then multiplying by 100.

My problem is I would like to put 'n/a' down as a result sometimes where a number value/score wasn't relevant. But when it comes to calculating the percentage it would be marked lower since it would be three less than the total possible.

So I assume there a few different ways I could tackle this problem, either by a formula that calculates the possible total based upon only the cells that have a numerical value or a formula which reads n/a as the value 3. But I can't seem to find something that works.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: what text are you reading as a number?

Comment: There isn't any included in the picture example but I would literally put "'n/a" in any of those cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

[image]

The countif() counts the n/a and multiplies by 3 to be subtracted from the 24.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I figured this out and the solution was far more simple that I thought it would be.

Originally the Score as % formula was `=SUM(T14/24*100)` 24 being the total is all cells were 3.

So what I've done is add a new column called possible total with the formula `=COUNT(K14:R14)*3` As the count function only counts cells that have a numerical value, thus will ignore any cells with n/a and since 3 is the maximum value that can be entered into the cell I've multiplied the count by 3.

Then it was a simple case of changing the score formula to `=SUM(T14/S14*100)` where the S column will be the new possible total.